# Como remover itens de um array?

Tags: javascript

```
    function converterBinario () {
       numero = document.getElementById("Valor-decimal").value;
       var vetor = [];
       var i =numero;
       var cont=0;
       while(i>0){

         var resto = Math.floor(numero % 2);

         if (resto == 0 | 1 ){
            vetor[i] = resto;
            console.log(resto);
         }

        numero= Math.floor(numero/2);
        console.log(numero);
        i--;
    }

document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML =vetor;
console.log(vetor);

}
```

Quero retirar os zeros do array que aparecem antes do 1.

Comment: Poderia ser mais claro na sua pergunta, um exemplo de como o array está e como deveria estar

Comment: Quer tirar todos os zeros da array?

Comment: Tirar todos antes do primeiro 1.O array está 0,0,0,1,0,1.Quero deixar 101.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode usar `filter()`:

```
vetor = vetor.filter(function(v,i){
   return i >= vetor.indexOf(1);
});
```

O `i >= vetor.indexOf(1)` irá retornar apenas os índices a partir da primeira ocorrência de `1` no vetor.

**Exemplo:**

```js
function converterBinario () {
   //       numero = document.getElementById("Valor-decimal").value;
   numero = 10;
   var vetor = [];
   var i =numero;
   var cont=0;
   while(i>=0){
   
      var resto = Math.floor(numero % 2);
   
      if (resto == 0 | 1){
         vetor[i] = resto;
      }
   
      numero= Math.floor(numero/2);
      //        console.log(numero);
      i--;
      
     
   }

   console.log("vetor original => ",vetor.join());

   vetor = vetor.filter(function(v,i){
      return i >= vetor.indexOf(1);
   });
   
   //document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML =vetor;
   console.log("vetor filtrado => ",vetor.join());

}

converterBinario();
```

Comment: Não entendi como funciona o  (return i >= vetor.indexOf(1);)

Comment: A funçao possui 2 parametros: v e i. "v" é o valor e "i" o índice. O filter irá percorrer a array retornando alguma coisa. O indexOf sempre encontra a primeira ocorrência, logo o return só irá retornar os itens da array cujo índice for igual ou maior do que a posição do primeiro item de valor 1 dentro da array.

Comment: Complementando, o filter só irá retornar os valores onde `i >= vetor.indexOf(1)` for `true`.